# JPA CrudRepository Disable New Element Insertion (Update Only)

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following repository interface for my user table.

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>
```

I want to **disable inserting new entities** into the user table and use the save function **only to update the existing entries** if there is one. How can I achieve that? Is there an option I can pass into the repository interface? Or should I override the save methods to do nothing when there is no matching entity?

Answer (score 2):

You can set this on the Entity mapping.

For example:

```
@Entity
public class User {

  @Id 
  @Column(insertable=false)
  private Integer id;

  @Column(insertable=false)
  private String name
```

Comment: But I want to disable a new user insertion altogether, not just selected columns. Also, I want to be able to update the columns on existing entries.

Comment: That's exactly what it will do if you set all columns to insertable=false